# Cannot resolve symbol builder when trying to Implement Stripe in Android

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I am attempting to implement payment in my application using Strip Documentation, but i am having some issues with the presentPaymentSheetMethod. I am following the docs precisely by using this site: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android, the issue I am confronted with is inside the presentPaymentSheet() method, builder and build  is in red, and it reads "Cannot resolve symbol builder/build" not sure what is the issue here, can someone assist me?

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.stripe.android.PaymentConfiguration;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.Fuel;
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelError;
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Handler;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.stripe.android.Stripe;
import com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget;
import org.varietyshoppe.varietyshoppe.Model.CartModel;
import org.varietyshoppe.varietyshoppe.R;
import org.varietyshoppe.varietyshoppe.adapter.CartAdapter;
import com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;



public class PaymentFragment extends Fragment {
    private View layoutView;
    public int pos = 0;
    private EditText cardEt, monthYearEt, cvcEt, nameEt, adressEt, cityEt, statEt, countryEt, zipEt;
    private String totalCost;
    private String uid;
    private Button paymentButton;
    private DatabaseReference cartDb;
    private CartAdapter cartAdapter;
    private String loggedInUserId;
    private ArrayList<String> priceArrayList, quantityArrayList;
    private RecyclerView cartRecyleView;
    private CartModel cartModel;
    private ArrayList<CartModel> cartModelArrayList;
    //server side stuff below this..



    // 10.0.2.2 is the Android emulator's alias to localhost
    // 192.168.1.6 If you are testing in real device with usb connected to same network then use your IP address
    EditText amountText;
    CardInputWidget cardInputWidget;
    // we need paymentIntentClientSecret to start transaction
    //declare stripe

    Double amountDouble = null;

    private OkHttpClient httpClient;

    static ProgressDialog progressDialog;




    // Stripe docs
    String paymentIntentClientSecret;
    PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration customerConfig;
    private Stripe stripe;
    PaymentSheet paymentSheet;

    private String paymentClientSecret;






    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_layout, container, false);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        bottomNav.setItemIconTintList(null);
        findViewById();
        getDataFromBundle();


        paymentSheet = new PaymentSheet(this, this::onPaymentSheetResult);


        Fuel.INSTANCE.post("Your backend endpoint/payment-sheet", null).responseString(new Handler<String>() {
            @Override
            public void success(String s) {
                try {
                    final JSONObject result = new JSONObject(s);
                    customerConfig = new PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration(
                            result.getString("customer"),
                            result.getString("ephemeralKey")
                    );
                    paymentIntentClientSecret = result.getString("paymentIntentClientSecret");
                    PaymentConfiguration.init(getContext(), result.getString("publishableKey"));
                } catch (JSONException e) { /* handle error */ }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(@NonNull FuelError fuelError) { /* handle error */ }
        });




        return layoutView;


    }











    //monthYearEt = expiry date
    public void findViewById() {
        nameEt = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.nameEt);
        adressEt = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.addressEt);
        cityEt = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.cityEt);
        statEt = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.stateEt);
        countryEt = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.countryEt);
        zipEt = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.zipEt);
        paymentButton = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.payButton);
        cardInputWidget = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.cardInputWidget);


        paymentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                presentPaymentSheet();


            }
        });

    }


    public void setUpFirebase() {
        cartDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        cartDb.keepSynced(true);

    }


    //navigate to different fragment...
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {

                        //Browse fragment - find stocks, etc...
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            //selectedFragment = new BrowseFragment();
                            break;

                        case R.id.message:

                            //selectedFragment = new MainSectorNewsFragmentUi();
                            break;


                        case R.id.profile:
                            //Trending stocks fragment..
                            //selectedFragment = new SecFeedsFragment();

                            //selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            };


    //get data from  cart fragment, via bundle, such as item cost.. uid.. etc..
    public void getDataFromBundle() {
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            totalCost = bundle.getString("TotalCost", "0");

            //populate payment button with total cost..
            paymentButton.setText("Pay " + "$" + (totalCost));

        }

    }



    private void presentPaymentSheet() {

        final PaymentSheet.Configuration configuration = new PaymentSheet.Configuration.Builder("Example, Inc.")
                .customer(customerConfig)
                // Set `allowsDelayedPaymentMethods` to true if your business can handle payment methods
                // that complete payment after a delay, like SEPA Debit and Sofort.
                .allowsDelayedPaymentMethods(true);
        .build();
        paymentSheet.presentWithPaymentIntent(
                paymentClientSecret,
                configuration
        );
    }


    //After the customer completes the payment, the sheet dismisses and the PaymentSheetResultCallback
    // is called with a PaymentSheetResult.
    private void onPaymentSheetResult(
            final PaymentSheetResult paymentSheetResult
    ) {
        if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Canceled) {
            Log.i("Payment Cancelled", "payment cancelled");

        } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Failed) {
            Log.e("App", "Got error: ", ((PaymentSheetResult.Failed) paymentSheetResult).getError());
        } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Completed) {
            // Display for example, an order confirmation screen
            //Log.d("Completed")
            Log.i("Order Completed..", "Order Completd...");

        }
    }






}




implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'



implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'




//firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'

implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:14.2.1'
// sor network call
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-java:20.77.0'
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:17.2.0'

implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.3.1'
 implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-json:2.3.1'








testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
`
```

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179389/why-am-i-getting-incompatible-types-when-trying-to-implement-stripe-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
 .allowsDelayedPaymentMethods(true);
        .build();
```

You have a semicolon ";" there so that's syntactically incorrect Java.