# Why am I getting Incompatible types when trying to implement stripe in Android?

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I am getting this error message when trying to implement stripe payment in my android application. This error comes from the presentPaymentSheet method.I am not sure why I am receiving this I am simply copying and pasting code from the strip official docs, so i am not sure where to go from here so if anyone can provide a solution or any hints on how to solve this then it will be greatly appreciated.

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.PaymentSheet.Configuration.Builder', required: 'com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.PaymentSheet.Configuration'





import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.Fuel;
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelError;
import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.Handler;
import com.stripe.android.PaymentConfiguration;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.stripe.android.Stripe;
import com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.varietyshoppe.varietyshoppe.Model.CartModel;
import org.varietyshoppe.varietyshoppe.R;
import org.varietyshoppe.varietyshoppe.adapter.CartAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.*;

import com.stripe.android.paymentsheet.*;
import com.stripe.android.PaymentConfiguration;




public class PaymentFragment extends Fragment {
    private View layoutView;
    public int pos = 0;
    private EditText cardEt, monthYearEt, cvcEt, nameEt, adressEt, cityEt, statEt, countryEt, zipEt;
    private String totalCost;
    private String uid;
    private Button paymentButton;
    private DatabaseReference cartDb;
    private CartAdapter cartAdapter;
    private String loggedInUserId;
    private ArrayList<String> priceArrayList, quantityArrayList;
    private RecyclerView cartRecyleView;
    private CartModel cartModel;
    private ArrayList<CartModel> cartModelArrayList;
    //server side stuff below this..
    private static final String BACKEND_URL = "http://192.168.1.6:4242/"; //4242 is port mentioned in server i.e index.js
    // we need paymentIntentClientSecret to start transaction
    private String paymentIntentClientSecret;
    //declare stripe
    private Stripe stripe;

    Double amountDouble=null;






    // 10.0.2.2 is the Android emulator's alias to localhost
    // 192.168.1.6 If you are testing in real device with usb connected to same network then use your IP address
    EditText amountText;
    CardInputWidget cardInputWidget;
    // we need paymentIntentClientSecret to start transaction
    //declare stripe


    static ProgressDialog progressDialog;




    // Stripe docs
    PaymentSheet paymentSheet;
    PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration customerConfig;





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.payment_layout, container, false);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = layoutView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);
        bottomNav.setItemIconTintList(null);
        findViewById();
        getDataFromBundle();

        paymentSheet = new PaymentSheet(this, this::onPaymentSheetResult);


        Fuel.INSTANCE.post("Your backend endpoint/payment-sheet", null).responseString(new Handler<String>() {
            @Override
            public void success(String s) {
                try {
                    final JSONObject result = new JSONObject(s);
                    customerConfig = new PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration(
                            result.getString("customer"),
                            result.getString("ephemeralKey")
                    );
                    paymentIntentClientSecret = result.getString("paymentIntentClientSecret");
                    PaymentConfiguration.init(getContext(), result.getString("publishableKey"));
                } catch (JSONException e) { /* handle error */ }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(@NonNull FuelError fuelError) { /* handle error */ }
        });






        return layoutView;


    }

private void presentPaymentSheet() {
    final PaymentSheet.Configuration configuration = new PaymentSheet.Configuration.Builder("Example, Inc.")
            .customer(customerConfig)
            // Set `allowsDelayedPaymentMethods` to true if your business can handle payment methods
            // that complete payment after a delay, like SEPA Debit and Sofort.
            .allowsDelayedPaymentMethods(true);
    .build()
    paymentSheet.presentWithPaymentIntent(
            paymentClientSecret,
            configuration
    );
}






 private void onPaymentSheetResult(
            final PaymentSheetResult paymentSheetResult
    ) {
        if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Canceled) {
            //Log.d("Canceled");
            Log.i("cancelled","cancelled");
        } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Failed) {
            Log.e("App", "Got error: ", ((PaymentSheetResult.Failed) paymentSheetResult).getError());
        } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Completed) {
            Log.i("Completed","Completed...");

        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a semicolon after `.allowsDelayedPaymentMethods(true);` before the `.build()` which means you are trying to assign the Builder to the variable instead of building it, and you should be getting a second error for the `.build()` which isn't being called on anything; you also need the semicolon after `.build()` or else the next line will be an error, too.

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72178286/cannot-resolve-symbol-builder-when-trying-to-implement-stripe-in-android/72183239#72183239